# Concatenate Ajax success function result set with a Dynamic Column Name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form with several form inputs with the following definition:

```
    <input type="text" name="aname" id="aname" class="form-control dataaccess" data-field="GID" />
<input type="text" name="sname" id="sname" class="form-control dataaccess" data-field="LID" />
```

Then i have an ajax function whose success function returns a resultset from the controller to display in the page. This is my code

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "controller/method",
data: "id="+data,
success: function(data){
 $(".dataaccess").each(function(){
     var field=data[0].($(this).data("field"));
     $("#"+$(this).attr("id")).val(field);
 });

});
```

However, my resultset is not getting concatenated with the fieldname i get from the respective input data-field attribute. Where am i getting it wrong? Thank you

Data returned by data:

```
[{"ID":"GR02","Name":"Admins","Valid":"30","Block":"No ","Descr":"Description"}]
```

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate  data[0]  and $(this).data("field") ?

Comment: @Govind Exactly. That what i am trying to do

Comment: Then use + operator instead "."

Comment: When i use it, data[0] is executed before attaching the column name. I want it to read data[0].LID and get the value therein.

Comment: Can you add data here which is returned by ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamic properties, you shouldn't use property accessor(.), you can use as index notation

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "controller/method",
    data: "id="+data,
    success: function(data){
     $(".dataaccess").each(function(){
         var self = this;  
         var field=data[0][$(self).data("field")];
         $("#"+$(self).attr("id")).val(field);
     });

    });
```

Define a reference to `this` as `self` outside the ajax call, so this can be available when ajax executes.

Comment: I tried that but the value of field becomes undefined because i think Javascript doesn't support associative arrays. Thank you

Comment: can u show me the data which is returned by ajax call

Comment: It return a resultset with row and columns from a database table

Comment: $(this).data("field") ... i think this is the mistake... As ajax calls are asynchronous, $(this) is refering to window/other so check the edited answer

Comment: This is refering to $(".dataaccess") element as per the code

Comment: put the ajax response in jsfiddle ans share me the link...i will just look into it

Comment: This answer is correct, and JavaScript does support associative arrays. Netizen, you need to check if data[0] returns an object, and $(this).data("field") returns string.

Comment: Thanks Nageshwar Reddy. My json data coming from the data variable was bad. Thank you for the multidimensional array concept. This is an object not an array as i had specified. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
success: function(data){
     $(".dataaccess").each(function(){
         var field=data[0].($(this).data("field"));
         console.log(field);
         $(this).val(field);
     });
});
```

Comment: data[0] is what i want to concatenate with $(this).data("field"). That is where my code is failing me. Thank you

Comment: so is it ok now, or there is still an issue?

Comment: There is an issue: .($(this).data("field")) is not a valid function or property to be preceded by a dot

Comment: try this :

var field=data[0]+($(this).data("field"));

Can you upload data value?

Answer (score 0):

**In JavaScript or JQuery + Operator used for concatenation:**

```
var field=data[0]+($(this).data("field"));
```

Comment: data[0] is immediately fired but i want both fired! I mean i want it to read data[0].LID and get the value in that column immediately

Comment: Please add  AJAX result data in your question.